# Opening a file in ruby

Tags: ruby

I tried opening a file in ruby with the following code but I got this unknown error message.

```
No such file or directory - -p
```

Code:

```
myfile=File.open("/home/cucumber/profiles/data.csv","r")
```

Please advice with the correct method to do.

Comment: Do you have any more code to show? I'm asking this, because ruby complains about an unknown directory "-p", while you do not even have the string "-p" in your snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure whether file exists in the designated location or not, either you check it manually or use in code:

```
File.exists?("/home/cucumber/profiles/data.csv")
```